# Converting older Mongo database references to DBRefs

Tags: mongodb

I'm in the process of updating some legacy software that is still running on Mongo 2.4. The first step is to upgrade to the latest 2.6 then go from there.

Running the `db.upgradeCheckAllDBs();` gives us the `DollarPrefixedFieldName: $id is not valid for storage.` errors and indeed we have some older records with legacy `$id, $ref` fields. We have a number of collections that look something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "1",
  "someRef" : {"$id" : "42",  "$ref" : "someRef"}
},
{
  "_id" : "2",
  "someRef" : DBRef("someRef", "42")
},
{
  "_id" : "3",
  "someRef" : DBRef("someRef", "42")
},
{
  "_id" : "4",
  "someRef" : {"$id" : "42",  "$ref" : "someRef"}
}
```

I want to script this to convert the older `{"$id" : "42",  "$ref" : "someRef"}` objects to `DBRef("someRef", "42")` objects but leave the existing DBRef objects untouched. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to differentiate between the two types of objects.

- Using `typeof` and `$type` simply say they are objects.
- Both have `$id` and `$ref` fields.
- In our groovy console when you pull one of the old ones back and one of the new ones getClass() returns DBRef for both.

We have about 80k records with this legacy format out of millions of total records. I'd hate to have to brute force it and modify every record whether it needs it or not.

This script will do what I need it to do but the `find()` will basically return all the records in the collection.

```
var cursor = db.someCollection.find({"someRef.$id" : {$exists: true}});
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  var rec = cursor.next();
  db.someCollection.update({"_id": rec._id}, {$set: {"someRef": DBRef(rec.someRef.$ref, rec.someRef.$id)}});
}
```

Is there another way that I am missing that can be used to find only the offending records?

**Update**

As described in the accepted answer the order matters which made all the difference. The script we went with that corrected our data:

```
var cursor = db.someCollection.find(
  {
    $where: "function() { return this.someRef != null &&
                          Object.keys(this.someRef)[0] == '$id'; }"
  }
);
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  var rec = cursor.next();
  db.someCollection.update(
    {"_id": rec._id},
    {$set: {"someRef": DBRef(rec.someRef.$ref, rec.someRef.$id)}}
  );
}
```

We did have a collection with a larger number of records that needed to be corrected where the connection timed out. We just ran the script again and it got through the remaining records.

There's probably a better way to do this. I would be interested in hearing about a better approach. For now, this problem is solved.

Comment: (Aside: Dave, the "What have you tried?" link in your profile now redirects to a homepage. It looks like the author has deleted their software engineering posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBRef is a client side thing. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs says it pretty clear:

> The order of fields in the DBRef matters, and you must use the above sequence when using a DBRef.

The drivers benefit from the fact that order of fields in BSON is consistent to recognise DBRef, so you can do the same:

```
db.someCollection.find({ $expr: { 
    $let: {
        vars: {firstKey: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $objectToArray: "$someRef" }, 0] } },
        in: { $eq: [{ $substr: [ "$$firstKey.k", 1, 2 ] } , "id"]}
    }
} } )
```

will return objects where order of the fields doesn't match driver's expectation.

Comment: Aha! I think that was the piece I was overlooking!

Comment: Sorry, just realised you need to run it in v2.4 where $expr is not available. No dice I'm afraid. On the bright side, you don't need to convert these fields to pass the validation. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/update/storage_validation.cpp#L62 suggests that `DollarPrefixedFieldName` error is reported for fields **excluding** DBRef set, so apparently you have something else there.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex. I think the issue is that our records are not DBRefs because the `$id` and `$ref` fields are reversed. We get `DollarPrefixedFieldName: $id is not valid for storage.` I presume because `$id` is the first field and if `$ref` was first we would not be in error. We're still investigating but I think you pointed us in the right direction.